# Make API call after form selection with React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I have a form with two dropdowns. The second dropdown list of options is returned by an API and depends on what the user selected in the first dropdown. How can I do this with React Final Form? Basically this involves:

1. The user selects an option from the first dropdown. This list is hardcoded
2. I make an API call and pass the selected option, the backend returns the list of options for the second dropdown
3. I update the form with the backend reponse

I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont create your own custom Select component, you can use something like this:

```
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';
  const { values } = useFormState();

  const [selectOptions2, setSelectOptions2] = useState([]);

  const fetchOptions = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await getOptions2();
      if (data.options) {
        setSelectOptions2(data.options);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(r);
    }
  }, [values.selectedOption1]);
```

And then use selectOptions2 as options for second Select.